# openshift content encoding error .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, openshift

I've just installed symfony2 on top of my wordpress 4.0 using the ekino-wordpress-bundle. I followed exactly the instructions here: https://github.com/ekino/EkinoWordpressBundle

Everything works fine on my localhost, a vanilla MAMP, however, when I push to openshift (also a vanilla php gear), everything breaks down and I get content encoding error.

I've tried tweaking the changes one by one and managed to narrow down the problem to the .htaccess file.

Here's the .htaccess file from wordpress that work:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /webfront-interiorpediadev/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /webfront-interiorpediadev/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Here's the symfony's .htaccess that break the wordpress, but if I changed back the htaccess, I got back the "only wordpress, no symfony" stuff like before:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    IndexIgnore /symfony
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .? - [L]

# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I have no idea what went wrong, as in my local MAMP, everything works perfectly with the faulty .htaccess (wordpress+symfony). Would anybody help pointing me to the right direction?

P.S: I've checked the LoadModule on both my MAMP and openshift and mod_rewrite is on. I have no idea about the rest but I think the difference is just mod_rewrite and autoindex

EDIT: the problematic url is: http://webfront-interiorpediadev.rhcloud.com/
note that all the other sub-urls are working fine, eg: http://webfront-interiorpediadev.rhcloud.com/wp-login or http://webfront-interiorpediadev.rhcloud.com/symfony/web

Comment: It looks like your local installation has all proper `ENV:*` set.

Comment: but everything underneath doesn't give encoding errors, see EDITs

Comment: I suspect the very last rewrite rule `RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]`. Though I never tried the env you are running, I would suggest you to play with this string: 1. move it three lines before or 2. remove it (I bet this would solve the problem.) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that you are doing your coding on windows, and then uploading to a linux web server, you should ssh into your gear and look at those files using vim and see what they look like.  It is very possible that you have some line ending issues, or that some character was copied as an html entity that shows up correctly in your IDE, but is not parsed correctly by the server.

Comment: I did my coding on OSX and test using MAMP (Mac, Apache, MySql, Php), but I'll try to check that again